# Can't load my twitter data .CSV file to Weka Explorer

Tags: machine-learning, weka, data-mining

Why giving not recognize as an 'CSV data files' file ? Can't load my twitter data .CSV file to Weka Explorer.

This is one row of my data. Help me to add this csv file to WEKA explorer.

example:

```html
Sat Sep 01 06:30:00 +0000 2018
1035776770966876162
1035776770966876162
Ooohhhh my brgy sa A nxt week for hype kids #Main...
Twitter for Android
False
null
null
null
null
null
224527163
224527163
  
meladylorie
null
null
null
none
False
False
205
273
4
1042
63685
Thu Dec 09 06:57:05 +0000 2010
null
null
True
en
False
False
94D487
http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme12/bg.gif
https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme12/bg.gif
False
7FDBB6
FFFFFF
FBF94E
2D3F0F
True
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/10193468908637...
https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1019346890863...
https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/224527163/15...
False
False
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
```

Error:
[image]

Please point me how to add twitter data set like mine to WEKA explorer.

Comment: I took your data snippet and saved it as a CSV file. It loaded fine, although everything is in one string attribute (i.e. data treated as rows) rather than one instance (i.e. data treated as columns, with your data being one row -- as you stated above).  Did you actually mean this is one row? If so, you are missing the column separator.

Comment: @zbicyclist this is a sample data file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RD6bJKpXZ1MOvS3tsf9kscRqREqHFtM-/view?usp=sharing   I used columns. can use this and leave a comment?

Comment: It's not really a CSV file, isn't it?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I got json file from twitter api and convert it to .csv

Comment: This is the sample of the file. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RD6bJKpXZ1MOvS3tsf9kscRqREqHFtM-

Comment: Well, I don't consider this to be a CSV.

Comment: Any tips how to use get twitter data and add to WEKA ? @Anony-Mousse I'm new to this

Comment: I downloaded the 11 rows in your Google Drive file. I spent some time with this, but no luck. It looks like your attribute names are too long. Weka loaders get particular about " and ' marks in the data fields and sometimes interpret them differently. You may want to use a different CSV delimiter other than a comma (e.g. a | character). Not sure why your rows look so very different from each other (e.g. about column ED and nearby).  Overall, I don't have enough domain knowledge about this file to be more helpful.  Good luck.